# Asp.net: path encoding

Tags: asp.net, url-encoding

I have an image gallery that I created by reading the contents inside a directory. Now right away I noticed a problem when there was a "+" in the filename. Like "glas + door.jpg" would break. So I thought it was an encoding problem and since it was only the "+" sign I thought that replacing the "+" with "%2b" would solve the problem. Locally the problem was fixed but when I uploaded it to my host I noticed replacing the "+" sign with "%2b" didn't work help anymore.

So this is where I started looking at the encoding possibilities of ASP.NET. I found `Server.UrlEncode` and `Server.UrlPathEncode`. This gave me some mixed results like images that worked before wouldn't work anymore.

So what's the correct way of encoding a path and why did the replace "trick" work on my PC but not in my hosting environment?

```
public List<fileInfo> RenderImages()
{
    List<fileInfo> RenderImages = new List<fileInfo>();
    var Images = GetImages();

    if (Images != null)
    {
        foreach (var Image in Images)
        {
            string FullPath = Path + FolderName + "/" + Image.Name.Replace("+", "%2b");
            string ImageName = Image.Name.Replace(Image.Extension, string.Empty);

            RenderImages.Add(new fileInfo { path = FullPath, name = ImageName });
        }
    }

    return RenderImages;
}    

public class fileInfo
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The `GetImages()` function gets jpg, gif and png `FileInfo`s from a certain directory. If needed, I can post that part of code also.

If it helps, [here](http://glasvandoren.sneak-peek.be/c-Glasvandoren/Deurgehelen_Op_Vloerveer) you can see how the images break. This is with `Replace("+", "%2b")`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Server.UrlEncode is the way to go.  Question: do you need the full path of the image to assign to the image src attributes?  Would RenderImages.Add(new FileInfo {path = "/" + Server.UrlEncode(FolderName + "/" + Image.Name), name = ImageName}); work better?

Comment: Yep, I need the full path. I tried encoding only the foldername and image.name and that also seems to work locally but on my host it breaks all the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that space can be escaped as + in URL:s and there is no way for a server to tell if you really mean + or space. Even when encoded as %2b it might be a double encoded space, so it will still turn out as a space when decoded.

To fix this, you can manually replace "+" with "%252b" instead, which will correctly decode as +.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real fix to my problem but I just replaced all the "+" signs with "plus". In the captation of the images I replaced it back with "+". It's just a work around because I wasn't able to solve my problem.